# LinkedIn API file_get_contents timing out

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I currently use `file_get_contents()` to call the LinkedIn Authentication API.

I successful call `/uas/oauth2/authorization` but when I call `/uas/oauth2/accessToken` with `file_get_contents()` it times out.

The odd thing is that it works perfectly on my localhost.

I've made sure `allow_url_fopen` is on and manage to open google.com with `file_get_contents()`.

As you can probably imagine, it's driving me crazy trying to debug it (and fix it).

Do any of you have any suggestions on why this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because `/uas/oauth2/accessToken` requires a POST type method, file_get_contents always uses GET. Consider switching to curl, method for both of your calls are provided below.

This information is available within the [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#accesstoken)

> Variables for both calls

```
$apiKey = '';
$state = '';
$scope = '';
$redirectUri = '';
```

> /uas/oauth2/authorization

```
$postData = http_build_query(
    [
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'client_id' => $apiKey,
        'scope' => $scope
        'state' => $state,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
    ]
);

$ch = curl_init();

$endpoint = sprintf('%s?%s', 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization', $postData);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

> /uas/oauth2/accessToken

```
$postData = http_build_query(
    [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => $apiKey,
        'scope' => $scope
        'state' => $state,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
    ]
);

$ch = curl_init();

$endpoint = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I really appreciate it. 

I tried your method, but I get the output `'{"error_description":"missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : client_id","error":"invalid_request"}'`

I then moved the post fields into the endpoint and it worked on my localhost but it throws a timeout error on my server.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: I also get this response: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set`.

Comment: on your server just change `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` to `false`

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. `curl_error($ch)` is outputting: `error:couldn't connect to host.` Do you think it's a server setting that I need to change?

Comment: well the fact that safe_mode is turned on is already going to cause you some problems. This feature has been completely removed as of PHP 5.4.0. If you are able to disable safe_mode then that will likely allow it to work. `safe_mode = 0` in your php.ini file

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.4.13. I've changed every setting under the sun and still no luck. Are there other ways to post this data?

Comment: sorry to say but I'm not really sure why it's not working, could be possible that your server isn't allowing the connection out.